# Convert an uploaded .PPM file to .PNG in PHP without installing ImageMagic or any other PHP module in Linux

Tags: php, png, file-conversion, ppm

I have a form in which a user is suppose to upload a *.ppm* file and I am suppose to convert the file to a valid *.png* file at the time of the upload.

I know how to do so with *ImageMagic* but in this case I don't have the liberty to install anything on the server, no PHP module or anything else.

I also cannot run any CLI command - only via the browser.

under these circumstances is there a way?

Comment: I'm sure there probably is a way. You'll just need to write all the code yourself, that's all. But...everyone else just asks their server adminstrator nicely to install the things they need. Either that or they move to a server host where this kind of common functionality is already available as standard.

Comment: by the way is: "ImageMagic" installation (including the PHP module which to my understanding requires an additional installation) - considered standard ?

Comment: It's not part of the basic PHP build, if that's what you mean. But it's very common for people to need it, so a lot of hosting companies have it installed on their servers already when you purchase an account, without you needing to ask them to add it.

Comment: So your PHP installation has no modules installed at all? No `readline`? Nothing listed if you run `phpinfo()` https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643880/how-can-i-create-a-phpinfo.php-page

Comment: I am voting to close this question if you don't follow up with answers to queries for clarification.

Comment: I didn't find a good way to do what I wanted without ImageMagic 
 but the host finally agreed to install ImageMagic so I guess case closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a good way to do what I wanted without ImageMagic but the webhost finally agreed to install ImageMagic so I guess case closed